# Arduino - Esp8266 12E read SD card file

Tags: sd-card, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to perform `JSON` file (**15.2KB [(15,601 bytes] of size**) read and write in `ESP8266 12E`. I'm using

1. Arduino SDK
2. ESP8266 12E
3. SD Card

I can:

1. Write the file using `HTTPClient`.
2. Read the file and print on `Serial` Monitor using following code:

   ```
   server.on("/read", []() {
   myFile = SD.open("commands.txt");

   byte thisByte;      
   if (myFile) {
       while (myFile.available()) {
           thisByte = myFile.read();
           Serial.write(thisByte);
       }
   }

   myFile.close();
   server.send(200, "text/html", "File read Success.");
   });
   ```

I ran `/read` 30 to 40 timesand it worked well without any error or ESP's `WDT` soft reset.

I can not:

1. Read the file in a `String` variable. Code is

   ```
   server.on("/read", []() {
   myFile = SD.open("commands.txt");

   String line = "";               
   if (myFile) {
       while (myFile.available()) {                
           line = myFile.readString();             
       }
   }

   Serial.println(line);

   myFile.close();
   server.send(200, "text/html", "File read Success.");
   });
   ```

after some `/read` **and/or** `/write` and then `/read` ESP reset.

```
Soft WDT reset

ctx: cont 
sp: 3fff0da0 end: 3fff10d0 offset: 01b0


3fff0f50:  00004e00 3fff0fb0 3fff0fb0 402095c3  
3fff0f60:  3fff0054 00004b73 3fff810f 4020a758  
3fff0f70:  00000001 3ffe9320 3fff0fd4 40206c54  
3fff0f80:  00000001 3ffe9320 3fff0074 4020a789  
3fff0f90:  00000001 3ffe9320 3fff0fd4 402092b9  
3fff0fa0:  00000001 3ffe9320 3ffefbac 4020245e  
3fff0fb0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 402095c3  
3fff0fc0:  6d6d6f63 73646e61 7478742e 40209600  
3fff0fd0:  3fff2d3c 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fff0fe0:  3fff359c 00004dff 00004df1 4010068c  
3fff0ff0:  00000000 00000001 3fff27dc 40206c4a  
3fff1000:  3fff27dc 3ffef308 3fff27dc 40206c86  
3fff1010:  00000000 00000000 00000000 40209770  
3fff1020:  3fff27dc 3ffef308 3ffef2c8 40206d19  
3fff1030:  3fff2d24 0000000f 00000005 40205b14  
3fff1040:  00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000f  
3fff1050:  00000001 3fff00a0 4020a114 3fff00b0  
3fff1060:  00000000 00000000 3ffef2c8 3fff00a0  
3fff1070:  00000001 3ffef2ec 3ffef2c8 40206f04  
3fff1080:  3ffe8d68 00000000 00001388 3fff00b0  
3fff1090:  00000000 3fff2c84 000003e8 3fff00a0  
3fff10a0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3fff0098 40202367  
3fff10b0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3fff0098 4020a160  
3fff10c0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3fff00b0 4010070c  
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)  
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16
```

I want to store the file data in a `String` variable and then process it line by line.

Full code is here:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>


IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 81);         // choose IP address
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
File myFile;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

//06519942-652e-11e7-907b-a6006ad3dba0

// SSID, PASSWORD
const char *ssid = "06519942-652e-11e7-907b-a";
const char *password = "password";

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);                      // so you can see debug messages automatically sent by ESP8266
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
    WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, subnet);        // declared as: bool softAPConfig (IPAddress local_ip, IPAddress gateway, IPAddress subnet)
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password, 7, 0, 1);  // network name, network password, wifi channel

    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
    Serial.println(myIP);
    delay(1000);

    // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

    Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(16)) {
        Serial.println("initialization failed!");
        return;
    }
    Serial.println("initialization done.");

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
        Serial.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }


    WiFiMulti.addAP("SSID", "PASSWORD"); // Change it with yours
    delay(1000);

    server.on("/", []() {
        server.send(200, "text/html", "Welcome");
    });

    server.on("/read", []() {
        myFile = SD.open("commands.txt");

        byte thisByte;      
        if (myFile) {
            while (myFile.available()) {
                thisByte = myFile.read();               
                Serial.write(thisByte);
            }
        }



        myFile.close();
        server.send(200, "text/html", "File read Success.");
    });

    server.on("/write", []() {
        HTTPClient http;

        Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");

        if (SD.exists("commands.txt")) {
            SD.remove("commands.txt");
            Serial.println("commands.txt removed.");
        }

        // configure server and url
        http.begin("http://controlxapi.azurewebsites.net/download");

        Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");

        // start connection and send HTTP header
        int httpCode = http.GET();

        if (httpCode > 0) {
            // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
            Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

            // file found at server
            if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {

                Serial.println("Creating commands.txt...");
                myFile = SD.open("commands.txt", FILE_WRITE);

                // get lenght of document (is -1 when Server sends no Content-Length header)
                int len = http.getSize();
                Serial.println(len);

                // create buffer for read
                uint8_t buff[128] = { 0 };

                // get tcp stream
                WiFiClient * stream = http.getStreamPtr();

                // read all data from server
                while (http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
                    // get available data size
                    size_t size = stream->available();

                    if (size) {
                        // read up to 128 byte
                        int c = stream->readBytes(buff, ((size > sizeof(buff)) ? sizeof(buff) : size));

                        // write it to Serial
                        //Serial.write(buff, c);
                        myFile.write(buff, c);

                        if (len > 0) {
                            len -= c;
                        }
                    }
                    delay(1);
                }
                stream->flush();
                myFile.close();
                Serial.println();
                Serial.print("[HTTP] connection closed. File write end.\n");

            }
        }
        else {
            Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
        }

        http.end();
        http.~HTTPClient();
        server.send(200, "text/html", "File write Success.");
    });

    //Start the server
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server(local) started");
}

void loop() {
    server.handleClient();
    //delay(100);
    if (WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(1000);
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is reading to

```
String line = "";
```

Never use String class for reliable performance.
Reason - this punctures your heap and leads to memory leaks -> crash and reset

for reading to send to browser as html, js, bmp and so on use this:

```
 const char* path = "\myfolder\myfile.html";

 FILE_SYSTEM can be either SD, SPIFFS, LittleFS

 File dataFile = FILE_SYSTEM.open(path, "r");
  ... do all sorts of checking if needed
 // e.g. contentType = F("text/html"); -> determined by a function analysing the  
 file extension 

 if (server.streamFile(dataFile, contentType) != dataFile.size()) {
}       // sends the file tothe browser
```

For just downloading to the PC set

```
 contentType = F("application/octet-stream")
```

A tip for Avr development. Get rid of the String class and stick to c-char arrays. In the beginning hard but pays of in the end.